# "High-hanging sign" or "High-hung" sign?

Tags: tense

What's the correct version and why?

Example:

> We found the hotel immediately, thanks to the friendly locals and
>   the hotel's **high-hung/high-hanging** sign.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible, but, here, I'd lean for ***'high hanging'***; because the past verb is already applied in 'found'. Now when you describe *the position* of the billboard, it's ***'hanging'***. This works especially when you are talking about just *past* and not *distant past*.

As I said, *high-hung* is also possible. But then, it'd be quite far past. I can think of an example:

> Historians say that keeping ***high-hung*** portraits of Gods and Goddesses in streets was the culture of that civilization.